# Complaint that FILE * is not initialized

Tags: c, visual-studio, file-io, fopen

```
void openUpNow(FILE *x, FILE *y)
{
    x = fopen("xwhatever", "r");
    y = fopen("ywhatever", "r");
}

int _tmain(int argc,  _TCHAR* argv[ ])
{   
    FILE *x, *y;

    openUpNow(x, y);
}
```

warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used

warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'y' used

Remedy?

Comment: None of the answers seem to point out that you should always check the return value from `fopen()`, just in case the open fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's what you want to do anyway.

Assuming you want `openUpNow()` to open the files into `x` and `y` you should use:

```
void openUpNow(FILE **x, FILE **y)
{
    *x = fopen("xwhatever", "r");
    *y = fopen("ywhatever", "r");
}

int _tmain(int argc,  _TCHAR* argv[ ])
{   
    FILE *x, *y;

    openUpNow(&x, &y);

    //  do stuff


}
```

In other words, you need to pass the address of the pointers `x` and `y` into the function.

As your code is right now, the call to `openUpNow()` doesn't do anything (and leaks the file-handles) since pointers are passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *x = NULL;
FILE *y = NULL;
```

Using Uninitialized variables often results in Undefined Behavior hence the compilers warn of it so that you can be aware of such variables.

Also, you need to pass the pointers by reference and not by value or what you get inside the function is a copy of the original pointer.

```
void openUpNow(FILE **x, FILE **y)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Corrected version:

```
void openUpNow(FILE **x, FILE **y)
{
    *x = fopen("xwhatever", "r");
    *y = fopen("ywhatever", "r");
}

int _tmain(int argc,  _TCHAR* argv[ ])
{   
    FILE *x = NULL;
    FILE *y = NULL;

    openUpNow(&x, &y);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that code is broken. In `_tmain`, `x` and `y` are uninitialized and have garbage values. Then you pass those values to `openUpNow`. Fortunately, `openUpNow` ignores them. But then you throw away the new values from the calls to `fopen`. You want:

```
void openUpNow(FILE **x, FILE **y)
{
    *x = fopen("xwhatever", "r");
    *y = fopen("ywhatever", "r");
}

int _tmain(int argc,  _TCHAR* argv[ ])
{   
    FILE *x, *y;

    openUpNow(&x, &y);
}
```